# find date is within range with moment failed

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have this array of object

```
[
  {
    "date_from": "2017-04-29 00:00:00",
    "date_to": "2017-05-02 23:59:59",
    "username":"john"
  },
  {
    "date_from": "2017-04-04 00:00:00",
    "date_to": "2017-04-08 23:59:59",
    "username":"james"
  },
  {
    "date_from": "2017-04-29 00:00:00",
    "date_to": "2017-05-02 23:59:59",
    "username":"jacob"
  }
]
```

I want to render some calendar, but the first step is to eliminate dates which is out of range.

I tried this function

```
function isDateWithinRage(date) {
    const when  = moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    console.log(when);
    const range = moment.range('2017-04-01','2017-04-30');

    return when.within(range);
}
```

Then I filter through the arr :

```
filter(arr, obj => isDateWithinRage(obj.date_from)) // returned empty [], why?
```

Anything wrong in my code? I couldn't find out.

Comment: Kindly mark the best answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Docs, it seems that, range limits must be `moment` object.

https://github.com/gf3/moment-range#create

```
function isDateWithinRage(date) {
    const when  = moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    const start = moment('2017-04-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    const end   = moment('2017-04-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    const range = moment.range(start, end);
    return when.within(range);
}

var filteredData = arr.filter((obj) => isDateWithinRage(obj.date_from))
```

Answer (score 2):

set variables:

```
//date to check
  let date = '2010-10-20';
//range
  let start = '2010-10-19';
  let end= '2010-10-25';
```

if using moment.js version 2.9.0 and above, use this:

```
return moment(date).isBetween(start, end);//returns true
```

if using a prior version use this:

```
if(date.diff(start) >= 0 && date.diff(end) <= 0) {
  result = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this solution.

```
function isDateWithinRage(date1,date2) {
if( moment("date1", "date format").diff(moment("date2", "date format"))
            >=0) {
                //Put your logic here
            }
```

Let me know if you further any query.